# How to use k-fold cross-validation with the 'patternnet' neural network in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, cross-validation, k-fold

I'm trying to use k-fold cross-validation with the `patternnet` neural network.

`inputs1` is a feature vector and `targets1` is label vector from 'iris_dataset'. And `xtrain`, `xtest`, `ytrain`, and `ytest` are training & testing features and labels respectively after splitting using the `cvpartition` function.

The steps are as follows:

1.First of all, a Pattern Recognition Network (`patternnet`) is Created.

```
In the first and second scripts: net = patternnet;
```

2.After dividing data into k-folds using `cvpartition`, two training & testing features and labels are created (`k=10`).

```
In the first and second scripts: fold = cvpartition(targets_Vec, 'kfold', kfold);
```

3.Then, the configure command is used to configure the network object and also initializes the weights and biases of the network;

```
In the first script: net = configure(net, xtrain', dummyvar(ytrain)'); % xtrain and ytrain are features and labels from step (2).
```

or

```
In the second script: net = configure(net, inputs1, targets1); % inputs1 and targets1 are features and labels before splitting up.
```

4.After initializing the parameters and hyper-parameters, the network is trained using the training data (by the `train()` function).

```
In the first script: [net, tr] = train(net, xtrain', dummyvar(ytrain)'); % xtrain and ytrain are features and labels from step (2).
```

or

```
In the second script: [net, tr] = train(net, inputs1, targets1); % inputs1 and targets1 are features and labels before splitting up.
```

5.And finally, the targets are estimated using the trained network (by the `net()` function).

```
In the first script: pred = net(xtest'); % testing features from step (2).
```

or

```
In the second script: pred = net(inputs1);
```

Since the training & testing features are separated using `cvpartition`, so the network should be trained using training features and its labels and then it should be tested by testing features (new data).

Although, the `train()` function is used for training the network, but it splits its own input (training data and labels from step (2)) into training, validation and testing data while the original testing data from step (2) remains unused.

Therefore, I need a function that is used training features and labels from step 2 (train and validation) for learning and also another function to classifying the new data (testing features from step 2).

After searching, I wrote two scripts, I think the first one isn't correct but I don't sure the second one is also incorrect or not? How to solve it?

The first script:

```
clc; close all; clearvars;
load iris_dataset
max_iter = 10;
kfold = 10;
[inputs, targets] = iris_dataset;  
inputs = inputs';
targets = targets';

targets_Vec= [];
for j = 1 : size(targets, 1)
    if max(targets(j, 1:3) == 1) && find(targets(j, 1:3))==1
        targets_Vec = [targets_Vec; 1];
    elseif max(targets(j, 1:3) == 1) && find(targets(j, 1:3))==2
        targets_Vec = [targets_Vec; 2];
    elseif max(targets(j, 1:3) == 1) && find(targets(j, 1:3))==3
        targets_Vec = [targets_Vec; 3];
    end
end

net = patternnet; ... Create a Pattern Recognition Network 

rng('default');     
... Divide data into k-folds
fold = cvpartition(targets_Vec, 'kfold', kfold);
... Pre
pred2 = []; ytest2 = []; Afold = zeros(kfold,1); 

... Neural network start
for k = 1 : kfold
    ... Call index of training & testing sets
    trainIdx = fold.training(k); testIdx = fold.test(k);
    ... Call training & testing features and labels
    xtrain = inputs(trainIdx,:); ytrain = targets_Vec(trainIdx);
    xtest = inputs(testIdx,:);   ytest = targets_Vec(testIdx);

    ... configure
    net = configure(net, xtrain', dummyvar(ytrain)');

    ... Initialize neural network
    net.layers{1}.name='Hidden Layer 1';
    net.layers{2}.name='Output Layer';
    net.layers{1}.size = 20;
    net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig'; 
    net.trainFcn = 'trainscg'; 
    net.performFcn = 'crossentropy'; 

    ... Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
    net.input.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
    net.output.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

    ... Train the Network
    [net, tr] = train(net, xtrain', dummyvar(ytrain)'); 
    ... Estimate the targets using the trained network.(Test)
    pred = net(xtest'); 

    ... Confusion matrix
    [c, cm] = confusion(dummyvar(ytest)',pred);        
    ... Get accuracy for each fold
    Afold(k) = 100*sum(diag(cm))/sum(cm(:));
    ... Store temporary result for each fold
    pred2 = [pred2(1:end,:), pred]; 
    ytest2 = [ytest2(1:end); ytest]; 
end

... Overall confusion matrix
[~,confmat] = confusion(dummyvar(ytest2)', pred2); 
confmat=transpose(confmat);
... Average accuracy over k-folds
acc = mean(Afold);
... Store results 
NN.fold = Afold;
NN.acc = acc; 
NN.con = confmat; 
fprintf('\n Final classification Accuracy (NN): %g %%',acc);
```

The second script:

```
clc; close all; clearvars;
load iris_dataset
max_iter = 10;
kfold = 10;
[inputs1, targets1] = iris_dataset;  
inputs = inputs1';
targets = targets1';

targets_Vec= [];
for j = 1 : size(targets, 1)
    if max(targets(j, 1:3) == 1) && find(targets(j, 1:3))==1
        targets_Vec = [targets_Vec; 1];
    elseif max(targets(j, 1:3) == 1) && find(targets(j, 1:3))==2
        targets_Vec = [targets_Vec; 2];
    elseif max(targets(j, 1:3) == 1) && find(targets(j, 1:3))==3
        targets_Vec = [targets_Vec; 3];
    end
end

net = patternnet; ... Create a Pattern Recognition Network

rng('default');     
... Divide data into k-folds
fold = cvpartition(targets_Vec, 'kfold', kfold);
... Pre
pred2 = []; ytest2 = []; Afold = zeros(kfold,1); 

... Neural network start
for k = 1 : kfold
    ... Call index of training & testing sets
    trainIdx = fold.training(k); testIdx = fold.test(k);
    ... Call training & testing features and labels
    xtrain = inputs(trainIdx,:); ytrain = targets_Vec(trainIdx);
    xtest = inputs(testIdx,:);   ytest = targets_Vec(testIdx);

    ... configure
    net = configure(net, inputs1, targets1);

    trInd = find(trainIdx);   tstInd = find(testIdx);
    net.divideFcn = 'divideind'; 
    net.divideParam.trainInd = trInd;
    net.divideParam.testInd = tstInd;

    ... Initialize neural network
    net.layers{1}.name='Hidden Layer 1';
    net.layers{2}.name='Output Layer';
    net.layers{1}.size = 20;                      
    net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'tansig'; 
    net.trainFcn = 'trainscg'; 
    net.performFcn = 'crossentropy';

    ... Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
    net.input.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
    net.output.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};

    ... Train the Network
    [net, tr] = train(net, inputs1, targets1);
    pred = net(inputs1); ... Estimate the targets using the trained network (Test) 

    ... Confusion matrix
    [c, cm] = confusion(targets1, pred);
    y = net(inputs1);
    e = gsubtract(targets1, y);
    performance = perform(net, targets1, y);
    tind = vec2ind(targets1);
    yind = vec2ind(y);  

    percentErrors = sum(tind ~= yind)/numel(tind);

    ... Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
    trainTargets = targets1 .* tr.trainMask{1};
%         valTargets = targets1 .* tr.valMask{1};
    testTargets = targets1 .* tr.testMask{1};
    trainPerformance = perform(net, trainTargets, y);
%         valPerformance = perform(net, valTargets, y);
    testPerformance = perform(net, testTargets, y);
    test_Fold(k) = testPerformance;

end

test_Fold_mean = mean(test_Fold);
acc = 100*(1-test_Fold_mean);   
fprintf('\n Final classification Accuracy (NN): %g %%',acc);
```